# How do i show date("l H:i") for when i submitted a post at my website?

Tags: php, social-networking

I made a social website where people from my class can ask questions and then it shows what time they uploaded the post, but i got 2 problems, first it's all in english and my website is danish. and the other problem is that it's showing what time it is when i'm refreshing. i made a while $row like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_posts_query)) {
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_date = date("l H:i")
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,100);
    $post_tags = $row['post_tags'];
    $post_comment_count = $row['post_comment_count'];
```

And searched through the internet but without luck.. Can you guys help me out on this one?

Comment: "first it's all in english and my website is danish" - that's not an issue, just use replace or google "localized date php". Secondly, "other problem is that it's showing what time it is when i'm refreshing" why is this an issue? You're using PHP to output this, so it's not magically going to update while you're on the site. You need javascript for something like that.

Comment: First of all check database if you are saving correct date and time of post. if its saving correct date and time then it should work perfect....

Answer (score 0):

"first it's all in english and my website is danish"

Check out this setlocale function http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Regarding why it shows you the current date, the answer is:
this returns the current date that the code beying evaluated

```
date("l H:i")
```

You need something like this:

```
date("l H:i", $row["someTimestampYouSaveWhenPostAdded"])
```